# How can I format this to print the month name instead of number?

Tags: java, format

This is a piece of the code I have so far... I need it to print out June 8, 2008 instead of 6/8/2014. How can I do this? If you need to see more of the other code, just ask.

```
    public void weatherRecord(int month, int date) {

    for (int loc = 0; loc < weatherRecord.length; loc++) {
        System.out.print("Location: " + weatherRecord[loc][month][date].getLocation() + "\t\t");
        System.out.print("Date: " + weatherRecord[loc][month][date+1].getDateToString() + "\n");
        System.out.print("High Temp: " + weatherRecord[loc][month][date].getHighTemp() + "\t\t\t");
        System.out.print("Low Temp: " + weatherRecord[loc][month][date].getLowTemp() + "\n");
        System.out.print("Avg Wind: " + weatherRecord[loc][month][date].getAvgWind() + "\t\t\t");
        System.out.print("Max Wind: " + weatherRecord[loc][month][date].getMaxWind() + "\n");
        System.out.print("Precipitation: " + weatherRecord[loc][month][date].getPrecip() + " inches.\n\n");

    }

}
```

Edit: I see other posts that talk about DateFormatSymbols, but how would I implement it?

Edit Edit: Here's the code that someone asked for...

```
public String getDateToString() {
    return "" + this.date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/"
            + this.date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/"
            + this.date.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " ";
}
```

Comment: Post the code that prints "6/8/2014"... I *presume* that it's `getDateToString()`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch posted it.

Comment: `new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()` returns array of string; `"January",  "February", "March"...` so you can simply use `new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[this.date.get(Calendar.MONTH)];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and something like

```
private static final DateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy");
public String getDateToString() {
    return SDF.format(date.getTime());
}
```

The four `M` characters become the full-name of the month. The single `d` is the day of the month and `yyyy` is a four digit year.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;

public String getDateToString() {
    return "" + monthNumToName(this.date.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + " "
            + this.date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + ", "
            + this.date.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " ";
}

private String monthNumToName(int month) {  
    return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];
}
```

Comment: How do I apply that to my code to get it to change it, though?

Comment: While this solution integrates well with your code as is please consider Elliott Frisch's solution.  I'll bet it will impress you with how it can simplify the problem.